# Align ImageView bottom to a RelativeLayouts top

Tags: android, android-layout, uiimageview, android-relativelayout

How can I align the **bottom** of an ImageView to the top of a RelativeLayout?

i.e:

I need this:

```
╔╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╗
║         ║
║ImageView║
║         ║
╚╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╝
╔╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╗
║         ║
║  RtvLyt ║
║         ║
╚╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╝
```

To something like this:

```
╔╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╤╗
║         ║
║ImageView║
║         ║
╠╪╪╪╪╪╪╪╪╪╣
║         ║
║  RtvLyt ║
║         ║
╚╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╧╝
```

Any idea how I can do this in XML?

Thanks.

Comment: Set alignParentBottom to true on your RelativeLayout, and then set your imageView on top of your RelativeLayout with "Above" and your RL's id

Comment: put them in a vertical linear layout for exemple ?

Comment: It depends on your root layout. If you're using vertical `LinearLayout`, you don't have to do anything. If you're using `RelativeLayout`, put `android:layout_above=@id/id_of_rtvlyt` for the `ImageView`

Comment: use vertical linear layout with spacing in between them its easy

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andrew T., The answer was to do `android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout"` on the ImageView.